# I'm working on a django project and anytime i activate the virtual environment the server will not run

Tags: python, django

I use vscode and it does not highlight any error though...django is also added to path

> This is the error

```
(myenv) C:\Users\GH\Desktop\Developments\The Blog\blogsite>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: You did install django in the virtual environment (with `pip install Django`)?

Comment: install django in the virtual environment (with pip install Django)...This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens and I don't know why. A few things you can do:

- always save your `venv` configuration: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`,
- check if the packages "missing" are actually installed,
- reinstall your virtual environment: deactivate and delete the old one, create a new one, then reinstall everything specified in `requirements.txt` (`pip install -r requirements.txt`)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Django is not installed in the current enviroment. Are you sure you activated your Virtual Enviroment?

Are you executing the server from terminal or from some VSCode interface? If so, try to execute directly from a terminal.

Also, it's not clear from your question if this is the first time you see the error. Did you grab this project from Git or somewhere else? Type `pip freeze` while Virtual Env activated and see the packages installed. Maybe you created the virtual enviroment but didn't installed the packages needed.